# MT5212: Native linking failed, duplicate symbol: '_OBJC_IVAR_$_FIRInstanceID._tokenManager'

Tags: ios, objective-c, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I have created iOS.dll file by binding the native objective c library. Untill now everything worked fine the xamarin ios app also worked fine. Now I have added Firebase frameworks (Firebase Auth, Database, Analytics, InstanceID) in my native objective c library to use firebase services and created the binding the same way I used to do before with xamarin iOS. However I am facing below error in xamarin iOS sample app when I include Firebase NuGet packages to implement firebase push notification.

Is there is any way to get rid of these errors or any way to remove or neglect the reference while making .dll

> clang : error : linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
>
> MTOUCH : error MT5212: Native linking failed, duplicate symbol: '_OBJC_IVAR_$_FIRInstanceID._tokenManager'.
>
> MTOUCH : error MT5213: Duplicate symbol in: /Users/Documents/adi/Xamarin/06062018/Test/obj/iPhoneSimulator/Debug/device-builds/iphone10.3-11.3/mtouch-cache/libMessageSDKFramework.a(FIRInstanceID_b1d502cebbd0a4f0a056073f0df0e3c0.o) (Location related to previous error)
>
> MTOUCH : error MT5213: Duplicate symbol in: /Users/Documents/adi/Xamarin/06062018/Test/obj/iPhoneSimulator/Debug/device-builds/iphone10.3-11.3/mtouch-cache/FirebaseInstanceID(FIRInstanceID_b1d502cebbd0a4f0a056073f0df0e3c0.o) (Location related to previous error)
>
> MTOUCH : error MT5212: Native linking failed, duplicate symbol: '_kFIRInstanceIDTokenRefreshNotification'.
>
> MTOUCH : error MT5213: Duplicate symbol in: /Users/Documents/adi/Xamarin/06062018/Test/obj/iPhoneSimulator/Debug/device-builds/iphone10.3-11.3/mtouch-cache/libMessageSDKFramework.a(FIRInstanceID_b1d502cebbd0a4f0a056073f0df0e3c0.o) (Location related to previous error)
>
> MTOUCH : error MT5213: Duplicate symbol in: /Users/Documents/adi/Xamarin/06062018/Test/obj/iPhoneSimulator/Debug/device-builds/iphone10.3-11.3/mtouch-cache/FirebaseInstanceID(FIRInstanceID_b1d502cebbd0a4f0a056073f0df0e3c0.o) (Location related to previous error)
>
> MTOUCH : error MT5212: Native linking failed, duplicate symbol: '_OBJC_IVAR_$_FIRInstanceID._retryCountForDefaultToken'.
>
> MTOUCH : error MT5213: Duplicate symbol in: /Users/Documents/adi/Xamarin/06062018/Test/obj/iPhoneSimulator/Debug/device-builds/iphone10.3-11.3/mtouch-cache/libMessageSDKFramework.a(FIRInstanceID_b1d502cebbd0a4f0a056073f0df0e3c0.o) (Location related to previous error)
>
> MTOUCH : error MT5213: Duplicate symbol in: /Users/Documents/adi/Xamarin/06062018/Test/obj/iPhoneSimulator/Debug/device-builds/iphone10.3-11.3/mtouch-cache/FirebaseInstanceID(FIRInstanceID_b1d502cebbd0a4f0a056073f0df0e3c0.o) (Location related to previous error)
>
> MTOUCH : error MT5212: Native linking failed, duplicate symbol: '_OBJC_IVAR_$_FIRInstanceID._isFetchingDefaultToken'.
>
> MTOUCH : error MT5213: Duplicate symbol in: /Users/Documents/adi/Xamarin/06062018/Test/obj/iPhoneSimulator/Debug/device-builds/iphone10.3-11.3/mtouch-cache/libMessageSDKFramework.a(FIRInstanceID_b1d502cebbd0a4f0a056073f0df0e3c0.o) (Location related to previous error)
>
> MTOUCH : error MT5213: Duplicate symbol in: /Users/Documents/adi/Xamarin/06062018/Test/obj/iPhoneSimulator/Debug/device-builds/iphone10.3-11.3/mtouch-cache/FirebaseInstanceID(FIRInstanceID_b1d502cebbd0a4f0a056073f0df0e3c0.o) (Location related to previous error)
>
> MTOUCH : error MT5212: Native linking failed, duplicate symbol: '_OBJC_IVAR_$_FIRInstanceID._defaultFCMToken'.
>
> MTOUCH : error MT5213: Duplicate symbol in: /Users/Documents/adi/Xamarin/06062018/Test/obj/iPhoneSimulator/Debug/device-builds/iphone10.3-11.3/mtouch-cache/libMessageSDKFramework.a(FIRInstanceID_b1d502cebbd0a4f0a056073f0df0e3c0.o) (Location related to previous error)
>
> MTOUCH : error MT5213: Duplicate symbol in: /Users/Documents/adi/Xamarin/06062018/Test/obj/iPhoneSimulator/Debug/device-builds/iphone10.3-11.3/mtouch-cache/FirebaseInstanceID(FIRInstanceID_b1d502cebbd0a4f0a056073f0df0e3c0.o) (Location related to previous error)
>
> MTOUCH : error MT5212: Native linking failed, duplicate symbol: '_OBJC_IVAR_$_FIRInstanceID._retryCountForCheckinRefresh'.
>
> MTOUCH : error MT5213: Duplicate symbol in: /Users/Documents/adi/Xamarin/06062018/Test/obj/iPhoneSimulator/Debug/device-builds/iphone10.3-11.3/mtouch-cache/libMessageSDKFramework.a(FIRInstanceID_b1d502cebbd0a4f0a056073f0df0e3c0.o) (Location related to previous error)
>
> MTOUCH : error MT5213: Duplicate symbol in: /Users/Documents/adi/Xamarin/06062018/Test/obj/iPhoneSimulator/Debug/device-builds/iphone10.3-11.3/mtouch-cache/FirebaseInstanceID(FIRInstanceID_b1d502cebbd0a4f0a056073f0df0e3c0.o) (Location related to previous error)
>
> MTOUCH : error MT5212: Native linking failed, duplicate symbol: '_OBJC_IVAR_$_FIRInstanceID._APNSTupleString'.
>
> MTOUCH : error MT5213: Duplicate symbol in: /Users/Documents/adi/Xamarin/06062018/Test/obj/iPhoneSimulator/Debug/device-builds/iphone10.3-11.3/mtouch-cache/libMessageSDKFramework.a(FIRInstanceID_b1d502cebbd0a4f0a056073f0df0e3c0.o) (Location related to previous error)
>
> MTOUCH : error MT5213: Duplicate symbol in: /Users/Documents/adi/Xamarin/06062018/Test/obj/iPhoneSimulator/Debug/device-builds/iphone10.3-11.3/mtouch-cache/FirebaseInstanceID(FIRInstanceID_b1d502cebbd0a4f0a056073f0df0e3c0.o) (Location related to previous error)
>
> MTOUCH : error MT5213: Duplicate symbol in: /Users/Documents/adi/Xamarin/06062018/Test/obj/iPhoneSimulator/Debug/device-builds/iphone10.3-11.3/mtouch-cache/libMessageSDKFramework.a(FIRInstanceIDAPNSInfo_3577655e8a036dca71b8fd8585feb607.o) (Location related to previous error)
>
> MTOUCH : error MT5213: Duplicate symbol in: /Users/Documents/adi/Xamarin/06062018/Test/obj/iPhoneSimulator/Debug/device-builds/iphone10.3-11.3/mtouch-cache/FirebaseInstanceID(FIRInstanceIDAPNSInfo_3577655e8a036dca71b8fd8585feb607.o) (Location related to previous error)
>
> MTOUCH : error MT5212: Native linking failed, duplicate symbol: '_OBJC_METACLASS_$_FIRInstanceIDAPNSInfo'.
>
> MTOUCH : error MT5213: Duplicate symbol in: /Users/Documents/adi/Xamarin/06062018/Test/obj/iPhoneSimulator/Debug/device-builds/iphone10.3-11.3/mtouch-cache/libMessageSDKFramework.a(FIRInstanceIDAPNSInfo_3577655e8a036dca71b8fd8585feb607.o) (Location related to previous error)
>
> MTOUCH : error MT5213: Duplicate symbol in: /Users/Documents/adi/Xamarin/06062018/Test/obj/iPhoneSimulator/Debug/device-builds/iphone10.3-11.3/mtouch-cache/FirebaseInstanceID(FIRInstanceIDAPNSInfo_3577655e8a036dca71b8fd8585feb607.o) (Location related to previous error)
>
> MTOUCH : error MT5212: Native linking failed, duplicate symbol: '_OBJC_IVAR_$_FIRInstanceIDAPNSInfo._deviceToken'.
>
> MTOUCH : error MT5213: Duplicate symbol in: /Users/Documents/adi/Xamarin/06062018/Test/obj/iPhoneSimulator/Debug/device-builds/iphone10.3-11.3/mtouch-cache/libMessageSDKFramework.a(FIRInstanceIDAPNSInfo_3577655e8a036dca71b8fd8585feb607.o) (Location related to previous error)
>
> MTOUCH : error MT5213: Duplicate symbol in: /Users/Documents/adi/Xamarin/06062018/Test/obj/iPhoneSimulator/Debug/device-builds/iphone10.3-11.3/mtouch-cache/FirebaseInstanceID(FIRInstanceIDAPNSInfo_3577655e8a036dca71b8fd8585feb607.o) (Location related to previous error)
>
> MTOUCH : error MT5212: Native linking failed, duplicate symbol: '_OBJC_IVAR_$_FIRInstanceIDAuthKeychainItem._account'.
>
> MTOUCH : error MT5213: Duplicate symbol in: /Users/Documents/adi/Xamarin/06062018/Test/obj/iPhoneSimulator/Debug/device-builds/iphone10.3-11.3/mtouch-cache/libMessageSDKFramework.a(FIRInstanceIDAuthKeyChain_4ca91bb1d332311cbe075921a00e2946.o) (Location related to previous error)
>
> MTOUCH : error MT5213: Duplicate symbol in: /Users/Documents/adi/Xamarin/06062018/Test/obj/iPhoneSimulator/Debug/device-builds/iphone10.3-11.3/mtouch-cache/FirebaseInstanceID(FIRInstanceIDAuthKeyChain_4ca91bb1d332311cbe075921a00e2946.o) (Location related to previous error)
>
> MTOUCH : error MT5212: Native linking failed, duplicate symbol: '_OBJC_IVAR_$_FIRInstanceIDAuthKeychain._identifier'.
>
> MTOUCH : error MT5213: Duplicate symbol in: /Users/Documents/adi/Xamarin/06062018/Test/obj/iPhoneSimulator/Debug/device-builds/iphone10.3-11.3/mtouch-cache/libMessageSDKFramework.a(FIRInstanceIDAuthKeyChain_4ca91bb1d332311cbe075921a00e2946.o) (Location related to previous error)
>
> MTOUCH : error MT5213: Duplicate symbol in: /Users/Documents/adi/Xamarin/06062018/Test/obj/iPhoneSimulator/Debug/device-builds/iphone10.3-11.3/mtouch-cache/FirebaseInstanceID(FIRInstanceIDAuthKeyChain_4ca91bb1d332311cbe075921a00e2946.o) (Location related to previous error)
>
> MTOUCH : error MT5212: Native linking failed, duplicate symbol: '_kFIRInstanceIDKeychainWildcardIdentifier'.
>
> MTOUCH : error MT5213: Duplicate symbol in: /Users/Documents/adi/Xamarin/06062018/Test/obj/iPhoneSimulator/Debug/device-builds/iphone10.3-11.3/mtouch-cache/libMessageSDKFramework.a(FIRInstanceIDAuthKeyChain_4ca91bb1d332311cbe075921a00e2946.o) (Location related to previous error)
>
> MTOUCH : error MT5213: Duplicate symbol in: /Users/Documents/adi/Xamarin/06062018/Test/obj/iPhoneSimulator/Debug/device-builds/iphone10.3-11.3/mtouch-cache/FirebaseInstanceID(FIRInstanceIDAuthKeyChain_4ca91bb1d332311cbe075921a00e2946.o) (Location related to previous error)
>
> MTOUCH : error MT5212: Native linking failed, duplicate symbol: '_OBJC_CLASS_$_FIRInstanceIDAuthKeychain'.
>
> MTOUCH : error MT5213: Duplicate symbol in: /Users/Documents/adi/Xamarin/06062018/Test/obj/iPhoneSimulator/Debug/device-builds/iphone10.3-11.3/mtouch-cache/libMessageSDKFramework.a(FIRInstanceIDAuthKeyChain_4ca91bb1d332311cbe075921a00e2946.o) (Location related to previous error)
>
> MTOUCH : error MT5213: Duplicate symbol in: /Users/Documents/adi/Xamarin/06062018/Test/obj/iPhoneSimulator/Debug/device-builds/iphone10.3-11.3/mtouch-cache/FirebaseInstanceID(FIRInstanceIDAuthKeyChain_4ca91bb1d332311cbe075921a00e2946.o) (Location related to previous error)
>
> MTOUCH : error MT5212: Native linking failed, duplicate symbol: '_OBJC_METACLASS_$_FIRInstanceIDAuthKeychain'.
>
> MTOUCH : error MT5213: Duplicate symbol in: /Users/Documents/adi/Xamarin/06062018/Test/obj/iPhoneSimulator/Debug/device-builds/iphone10.3-11.3/mtouch-cache/libMessageSDKFramework.a(FIRInstanceIDAuthKeyChain_4ca91bb1d332311cbe075921a00e2946.o) (Location related to previous error)
>
> MTOUCH : error MT5213: Duplicate symbol in: /Users/Documents/adi/Xamarin/06062018/Test/obj/iPhoneSimulator/Debug/device-builds/iphone10.3-11.3/mtouch-cache/FirebaseInstanceID(FIRInstanceIDAuthKeyChain_4ca91bb1d332311cbe075921a00e2946.o) (Location related to previous error)
>
> MTOUCH : error MT5212: Native linking failed, duplicate symbol: '_OBJC_CLASS_$_FIRInstanceIDAuthKeychainItem'.
>
> MTOUCH : error MT5213: Duplicate symbol in: /Users/Documents/adi/Xamarin/06062018/Test/obj/iPhoneSimulator/Debug/device-builds/iphone10.3-11.3/mtouch-cache/libMessageSDKFramework.a(FIRInstanceIDAuthKeyChain_4ca91bb1d332311cbe075921a00e2946.o) (Location related to previous error)
>
> MTOUCH : error MT5213: Duplicate symbol in: /Users/Documents/adi/Xamarin/06062018/Test/obj/iPhoneSimulator/Debug/device-builds/iphone10.3-11.3/mtouch-cache/FirebaseInstanceID(FIRInstanceIDAuthKeyChain_4ca91bb1d332311cbe075921a00e2946.o) (Location related to previous error)
>
> MTOUCH : error MT5212: Native linking failed, duplicate symbol: '_OBJC_METACLASS_$_FIRInstanceIDAuthKeychainItem'.
>
> MTOUCH : error MT5213: Duplicate symbol in: /Users/Documents/adi/Xamarin/06062018/Test/obj/iPhoneSimulator/Debug/device-builds/iphone10.3-11.3/mtouch-cache/libMessageSDKFramework.a(FIRInstanceIDAuthKeyChain_4ca91bb1d332311cbe075921a00e2946.o) (Location related to previous error)
>
> MTOUCH : error MT5213: Duplicate symbol in: /Users/Documents/adi/Xamarin/06062018/Test/obj/iPhoneSimulator/Debug/device-builds/iphone10.3-11.3/mtouch-cache/FirebaseInstanceID(FIRInstanceIDAuthKeyChain_4ca91bb1d332311cbe075921a00e2946.o) (Location related to previous error)
>
> MTOUCH : error MT5212: Native linking failed, duplicate symbol: '_OBJC_IVAR_$_FIRInstanceIDAuthKeychainItem._modificationDate'.
>
> MTOUCH : error MT5213: Duplicate symbol in: /Users/Documents/adi/Xamarin/06062018/Test/obj/iPhoneSimulator/Debug/device-builds/iphone10.3-11.3/mtouch-cache/libMessageSDKFramework.a(FIRInstanceIDAuthKeyChain_4ca91bb1d332311cbe075921a00e2946.o) (Location related to previous error)
>
> MTOUCH : error MT5213: Duplicate symbol in: /Users/Documents/adi/Xamarin/06062018/Test/obj/iPhoneSimulator/Debug/device-builds/iphone10.3-11.3/mtouch-cache/FirebaseInstanceID(FIRInstanceIDAuthKeyChain_4ca91bb1d332311cbe075921a00e2946.o) (Location related to previous error)
>
> MTOUCH : error MT5212: Native linking failed, duplicate symbol: '_OBJC_IVAR_$_FIRInstanceIDAuthKeychainItem._service'.
>
> MTOUCH : error MT5213: Duplicate symbol in: /Users/Documents/adi/Xamarin/06062018/Test/obj/iPhoneSimulator/Debug/device-builds/iphone10.3-11.3/mtouch-cache/libMessageSDKFramework.a(FIRInstanceIDAuthKeyChain_4ca91bb1d332311cbe075921a00e2946.o) (Location related to previous error)
>
> MTOUCH : error MT5213: Duplicate symbol in: /Users/Documents/adi/Xamarin/06062018/Test/obj/iPhoneSimulator/Debug/device-builds/iphone10.3-11.3/mtouch-cache/FirebaseInstanceID(FIRInstanceIDAuthKeyChain_4ca91bb1d332311cbe075921a00e2946.o) (Location related to previous error)
>
> MTOUCH : error MT5212: Native linking failed, duplicate symbol: '_OBJC_IVAR_$_FIRInstanceIDAuthKeychain._generic'.
>
> MTOUCH : error MT5213: Duplicate symbol in: /Users/Documents/adi/Xamarin/06062018/Test/obj/iPhoneSimulator/Debug/device-builds/iphone10.3-11.3/mtouch-cache/libMessageSDKFramework.a(FIRInstanceIDAuthKeyChain_4ca91bb1d332311cbe075921a00e2946.o) (Location related to previous error)
>
> MTOUCH : error MT5213: Duplicate symbol in: /Users/Documents/adi/Xamarin/06062018/Test/obj/iPhoneSimulator/Debug/device-builds/iphone10.3-11.3/mtouch-cache/FirebaseInstanceID(FIRInstanceIDAuthKeyChain_4ca91bb1d332311cbe075921a00e2946.o) (Location related to previous error)
>
> MTOUCH : error MT5212: Native linking failed, duplicate symbol: '_OBJC_IVAR_$_FIRInstanceIDAuthKeychainItem._data'.
>
> MTOUCH : error MT5213: Duplicate symbol in: /Users/Documents/adi/Xamarin/06062018/Test/obj/iPhoneSimulator/Debug/device-builds/iphone10.3-11.3/mtouch-cache/libMessageSDKFramework.a(FIRInstanceIDAuthKeyChain_4ca91bb1d332311cbe075921a00e2946.o) (Location related to previous error)
>
> MTOUCH : error MT5213: Duplicate symbol in: /Users/Documents/adi/Xamarin/06062018/Test/obj/iPhoneSimulator/Debug/device-builds/iphone10.3-11.3/mtouch-cache/FirebaseInstanceID(FIRInstanceIDAuthKeyChain_4ca91bb1d332311cbe075921a00e2946.o) (Location related to previous error)
>
> MTOUCH : error MT5212: Native linking failed, duplicate symbol: '_OBJC_IVAR_$_FIRInstanceIDAuthService._checkinRetryCount'.
>
> MTOUCH : error MT5213: Duplicate symbol in: /Users/Documents/adi/Xamarin/06062018/Test/obj/iPhoneSimulator/Debug/device-builds/iphone10.3-11.3/mtouch-cache/libMessageSDKFramework.a(FIRInstanceIDAuthService_41557c1c330f90e42c16c2ecb85001e4.o) (Location related to previous error)
>
> MTOUCH : error MT5213: Duplicate symbol in: /Users/Documents/adi/Xamarin/06062018/Test/obj/iPhoneSimulator/Debug/device-builds/iphone10.3-11.3/mtouch-cache/FirebaseInstanceID(FIRInstanceIDAuthService_41557c1c330f90e42c16c2ecb85001e4.o) (Location related to previous error)
>
> MTOUCH : error MT5212: Native linking failed, duplicate symbol: '_OBJC_IVAR_$_FIRInstanceIDAuthService._isCheckinInProgress'.
>
> MTOUCH : error MT5213: Duplicate symbol in: /Users/Documents/adi/Xamarin/06062018/Test/obj/iPhoneSimulator/Debug/device-builds/iphone10.3-11.3/mtouch-cache/libMessageSDKFramework.a(FIRInstanceIDAuthService_41557c1c330f90e42c16c2ecb85001e4.o) (Location related to previous error)
>
> MTOUCH : error MT5213: Duplicate symbol in: /Users/Documents/adi/Xamarin/06062018/Test/obj/iPhoneSimulator/Debug/device-builds/iphone10.3-11.3/mtouch-cache/FirebaseInstanceID(FIRInstanceIDAuthService_41557c1c330f90e42c16c2ecb85001e4.o) (Location related to previous error)
>
> MTOUCH : error MT5212: Native linking failed, duplicate symbol: '_OBJC_IVAR_$_FIRInstanceIDAuthService._checkinHandlers'.
>
> MTOUCH : error MT5213: Duplicate symbol in: /Users/Documents/adi/Xamarin/06062018/Test/obj/iPhoneSimulator/Debug/device-builds/iphone10.3-11.3/mtouch-cache/libMessageSDKFramework.a(FIRInstanceIDAuthService_41557c1c330f90e42c16c2ecb85001e4.o) (Location related to previous error)
>
> MTOUCH : error MT5213: Duplicate symbol in: /Users/Documents/adi/Xamarin/06062018/Test/obj/iPhoneSimulator/Debug/device-builds/iphone10.3-11.3/mtouch-cache/FirebaseInstanceID(FIRInstanceIDAuthService_41557c1c330f90e42c16c2ecb85001e4.o) (Location related to previous error)
>
> MTOUCH : error MT5202: Native linking failed. Please review the build log.

Answer (score 0):

I just got to fix the same issue this morning.
Unfortunately there is no proper solution currently but a workaround:

> ..we discover this issue like two weeks ago, this only happens in
> simulator AFAIK. Seems that the dependency LevelDB left their Main
> symbol. I'll file a bug on Firebase. The workaround for this is to
> change the behavior of the Registrar on Simulator:
>
> 1. Open your project settings
> 2. Go to Build tab
> 3. Select iOS Build option
> 4. Type --registrar:static in Additional mtouch arguments textbox
> 5. Click on Ok
>
> Don't forget to add this in Release and Debug configuration of
> iPhoneSimulator platform.

More details can be found [here](https://github.com/xamarin/GoogleApisForiOSComponents/issues/111#issuecomment-346887313).

Comment: I have already tried this however it is not working. Thank you for your help. @EvZ