# Native linking failed, duplicate symbol: _WebP

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I'm working on Xamarin.iOS 12.99 (last release, updated yesterday).

Now, when i try to compile my app, i get the error messages:

"Native linking failed, duplicate symbol: '_WebPMultRow_C'"

"Native linking failed, duplicate symbol: '_WebPMultRows'"

"Native linking failed, duplicate symbol: '_WebPMultARGBRow_C'.

"Native linking failed, duplicate symbol: '_VP8LReadBits'"

I tried to clean the project solution and the error message persists. I'm stucked in this. Can anyone help?

Comment: No. I'm not. :(

Comment: Is that happen after you updating the Xamarin.iOS version? You can try the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50795398/mt5212-native-linking-failed-duplicate-symbol-objc-ivar-firinstanceid-to). Also, read the document about this error: [native-linking-failed-duplicate-symbol-](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/troubleshooting/mtouch-errors#mt5212-native-linking-failed-duplicate-symbol-)